# accumulators don't compile

Tags: c++, boost, accumulator

HI All

I am using boost accumulators.

These 2 lines use to work fine with current version of boost in LInux.

```
accumulator_set< double, stats< tag::covariance<double, tag::covariate1> > >
acc_cov;
accumulator_set< double, stats< tag::variance > > acc_var;
```

When I moved to a Sun machine where it is installed boost v1.40
I have this building error

```
"/opt/boost/boost/accumulators/framework/depends_on.hpp", line 276:
Error:<no tag> cannot be initialized in a constructor.
"/opt/boost/boost/fusion/container/list/cons.hpp", line 85: Where: While
instantiating "boost::accumulators::detail::accumulator_wrapper<int,
int>::accumulator_wrapper(const
boost::accumulators::detail::accumulator_wrapper<int, int>&)".
"/opt/boost/boost/fusion/container/list/cons.hpp", line 85: Where:
Instantiated from non-template code.
1 Error(s)
```

Do you know how can I fix those errors and why I have this issue?

Thanks 
AFG

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same version of Boost on both machines?

Also, Sun and x86 machines are quite different, so you may be running into problems there as well.

Comment: No they have different version.
Do you know how to fix this issue chaging those lines?